# Smalltalk: context cannot return

Tags: closures, block, smalltalk

The following Smalltalk code returns the error "context cannot return" if I execute them one by one. Anyone has an explanation please?

```
  f := [ :x :y | ^x + y].
  sum:= f value: 3 value: 6.
```

If I execute them at one go, it works and returns `9` as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to write

```
f := [ :x :y | x + y].
sum:=f value: 3 value: 6.
```

### Why?

Let me tell you about

#### Non-local returns.

When you want to return something from a method, you use the `^` caret in a method to do so:

```
doSomethingUseful
    ^ self calculate + 1
```

This is a normal return. Everything ok. Now enter blocks.

You *always* implicitly return something from a block, the value of its last expression.
So, this block would return `42`, when executed:

```
[1 + someObject invert.
 anotherObject * 4.
 42].
```

You can use that in methods:

```
doSomethingUseful: someObject to: anotherObject
    | myValue |
    myValue := [1 + someObject invert.
                anotherObject * 4.
                42] value.
    ^ self calculate + myValue
```

However, sometimes you have to return *from the block out of the function*.
A typical example are *guard clauses* like this:

```
doThis
    self someValueSatisfied ifFalse: [^ self]
    self calculate.
    ^ self someValueComputed.
```

If `#someValueSatsified` returns `false`, the method immediately returns and never executes `#calculate` or `#someValueComputed`. This effect is called a **non-local return** because you return from the block *not* to its calling context (which would be local) but form the method it is defined in (!).

### Why does it work in one go?

This is due to the way “Do-its” are handled in, eg. Squeak or Pharo. When you hit Ctrl-D (or equivalent), the *currently selected* code is secretly compiled as a method (well, there happens a little bit more, but lets ignore that). You can see that if you execute `1 halt` and look at the debugger.

So executing the code line-wise would do the following:

```
DoIt
    f := [ :x :y |    ^(x+y). ]. "! f is now defined in the work space"

DoIt
    sum:=f value: 3 value: 6.
```

First, the block is created and stored somewhere in your workspace as `f`. Then this do-it exits and the next is executed. Smalltalk finds `f` in your workspace, being the stored block. It tries to execute it and encounters the non-local return. However, the non-local return only returns from the *defining* function, which is no longer executed and so we cannot return from it.

When you execute everything in one go, this would be like:

```
DoIt
    f := [ :x :y |    ^(x+y). ].
    sum:=f value: 3 value: 6.
```

Nearly the same as above, *except* that now when `f` is executed, the non-local return *can* work, as we still are in the function that defined the block. So we can return from it. The non-local return works in this case.